C++ std::filesystem, recursively and asynchronously counting files in a changing filesystem
I am trying to find a way to recursively list files in a changing filesystem but keep running into an errors in the /proc directory.
#include <list>
#include <unordered_set>

class directory_pile : public std::unordered_set<std::string>
{
    std::mutex usage_mutex;

public:
    bool contains(const std::string &dir_name)
    {
        std::lock_guard lg(usage_mutex);
        if (this->find(dir_name) == this->end())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void add(const std::string &dir_name)
    {
        std::lock_guard lg(usage_mutex);
        this->emplace(dir_name);
    }
};

static int count_files(const std::string &path, directory_pile *dir_pile)
{
    if (dir_pile->contains(path))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    dir_pile->add(path);
    int i = 0;
    std::list<std::future<int>> futures;
    for (const auto &entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        if (entry.is_directory() && entry.exists())
        {
            const std::string p = entry.is_symlink() ? std::filesystem::canonical(entry.path()) : entry.path();
            futures.push_back(std::async(count_files, p, dir_pile)); // std::async(count_files, entry.path(), dir_pile));
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (auto &f : futures)
    {
        i += f.get();
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    directory_pile *dir_pile = new directory_pile();
    std::cout << count_files(std::filesystem::current_path(), dir_pile) << std::endl;
}

The directory_pile class is to keep track of directories I have already visited in order to handle looping sym links.  In my environment I have a sym link to / taking me back to the root of the file system.  My program keeps throwing an exception like this:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot make canonical path: No such file or directory [/proc/91169/fd/14]
Aborted

Which makes total sense because /proc always has files being added and deleted while the code runs.  I tried wrapping canonical path in a try catch but that made the program run forever because it kept searching news created processes.
I found a post saying this was possible with nftw, but that made the asynchronous part of this problem very tedious.  Is there a std::filesystem way to solve this problem?

I wouldn't expect anything to really be able to handle /proc like that; it's not a normal filesystem in any way. I know Linux is a bit stingy when it comes to actual APIs, but what are you trying to accomplish with this?

What do you think that async call is doing?

@Yakk Recursively calling the function with a new dir path in a new thread.  Is it not?
